# Trying to increment a string pointer in C

Tags: c, string, pointers

Basically what I am trying to do is take a simple string like `abcd` and add it to a new string with asterisks in-between each letter like so, `a*b*c*d`. But it seems I am having issues with the function that is supposed to do this. Here is my code.

```
char widen_stars(char *user1p, char *user2p) {

    char *newStr;

    newStr = malloc(20 * sizeof(int));

    while (*user1p)  {
        *newStr = *user1p;
        //return printf("Test: %s \n", newStr);
        newStr++;
        //return printf("Test: %s \n", newStr);
        user1p++;
        *newStr = '*';
        newStr++;
    }

    return printf("String with asterisks: %s \n", newStr);
}
```

What I am trying to do is make a new string where I add in one letter from the original and then the asterisk right after, then increment and continue the cycle.

Where I am experiencing the problem is at the second `return printf test` it keeps on printing out nothing, but at the first `return printf test` it shows I've moved the first character over successfully, I'm not sure what's going on. New to programming so any help is appreciated.

Comment: When you do `printf("%s\n", newStr);` newStr is pointing to the end of the new string...

Comment: Null terminator, and if you increment the Pinter, you need to keep a record of the start value so you can print it and free it.

Comment: How would I make it print the whole thing then? Do I need to assign it to another pointer variable?

Comment: @immibis is not quite correct.  In the first iteration of the loop,  newStr indeed points to the 2nd character that was allocated, but that value is not necessarily a nul terminator.  Its value is indeterminate, since it was never initialized.

Comment: `malloc(20*sizeof(int))` doesn't make any sense -- you're storing a string, not an array of 20 ints.  You probably want `malloc(2*strlen(user1p) + 1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to keep the original newStr value. And zero terminate it too.

```
char widen_stars(char *user1p, char *user2p) {

char *newStr;
newStr = malloc(20 * sizeof(int));
char *keep = newstr;    // save start of new string
while (*user1p)  {
    *newStr = *user1p;
    //return printf("Test: %s \n", newStr);
    newStr++;
    //return printf("Test: %s \n", newStr);
    user1p++;
    *newStr = '*';
    newStr++;
}
*newstr  = '\0'; // zero terminate new string
return printf("String with asterisks: %s \n", keep); // print it
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I actually tried that before but it wasn't working either, turns out I was allocating the memory after the `char *keep = newStr` so that's why it wasn't working!

Comment: While freeing the memory, you now have to `free(keep)` and not `free(newstring)` as `keep` has the original location that was allocated.